# Split Data Into Multiple Worksheets Based On Data in 1 Column

Tags: excel, vba

I came across a very useful script to divide data. However I need it to copy and paste values and not formulas. Could you help me adjust the script. I cannot seem to make it work.

Another thing that does not work is copying the headers in the table. Does this has something to do with the headers being on row no 3 and then the data starts at row no 4? I solved it by adding a cleanup-VBA that copies the headers and cleans up the empty rows created. But maybe the code below can be adjusted instead?

Thank you smart people! :-)

Reference to the code: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1174-excel-split-data-into-multiple-worksheets-based-on-column.html

```vb
Sub Splitdatabycol()
    'updateby Extendoffice
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer
    Dim xTRg As Range
    Dim xVRg As Range
    Dim xWSTRg As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set xTRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the header rows:", "Kutools for Excel", "", Type:=8)
    If TypeName(xTRg) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
    
    Set xVRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the column you want to split data based on:", "Kutools for Excel", "", Type:=8)
    If TypeName(xVRg) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
    
    vcol = xVRg.Column
    Set ws = xTRg.Worksheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = xTRg.AddressLocal
    titlerow = xTRg.Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('xTRgWs_Sheet!A1')") Then
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "xTRgWs_Sheet"
    Else
        Sheets("xTRgWs_Sheet").Delete
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "xTRgWs_Sheet"
    End If
    
    Set xWSTRg = Sheets("xTRgWs_Sheet")
    xTRg.Copy
    xWSTRg.Paste Destination:=xWSTRg.Range("A1")
    ws.Activate
    
    For i = (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count) To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next
    
    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        xWSTRg.Range(title).Copy
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Paste Destination:=Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        ws.Range("A" & (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count) & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A" & (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count))
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    
    xWSTRg.Delete
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `xWSTRg.Paste Destination:=xWSTRg.Range("A1")` to `xWSTRg.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.

Comment: Alternatively try `xWSTRg.Range("A1").Resize(xTRg.Rows.Count, xTRg.Columns.Count).Value = xTRg.Value`. This is much faster than copying and pasting.